# How can I pass command line argument

Tags: linux

I want to pass a parameter in command and that need to execute.

For example:

```
read -s -p "ls -ltr " $1
```

Then I will pass parameter `$1` -> `abc*`. It should execute and provide the files with `abc*`

```
read -s -p "ls -ltr " $1

read -s -p "ls -ltr " $1
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, you just can't read into a positional variable.

```
read -s -p "ls -ltr " mask
ls -ltr $mask
```

I don't understand why you're hiding the input, though?

P.S.: This *won't* work for filenames w/ e.g. spaces in them, or if you enter multiple space separated masks ...

Comment: Actually it should read my argument and need to execute that what is my request.
i.e
if i pass argument ab*
it need to execute as below
ls -tlr ab*

Comment: Actually I have no idea what you just tried to convey. If your original question doesn't  reflect what you meant to say, edit it.

Comment: I will put it in simple way
ls -ltr abc* 
I need to pass parameter abc* to ls -tlr  , how do i achieve it ?

Comment: you can't read interactively and execute from the same command ... and the two steps in my answer do what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

You can access passed arguments with $n where n is the argument number - 1, 2, 3, .... You pass the arguments just like you would with any other command.

`$ cat myscript`

`#!/bin/bash`

`echo "First arg: $1"`

`echo "Second arg: $2"`

`$ ./myscript hello world`

`First arg: hello`

`Second arg: world`